# Non english characters in Kodi API

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest, kodi

I am using the [Kodi API](http://kodi.wiki/view/JSON-RPC_API/v6), to control my htpc via asp.net.
Especialy the functio named "Playlist.Add".
The Json I send is like this:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Playlist.Insert","params":{"playlistid":0,"position":0,"item":{"file":"smb://server/Ferry Corsten/Beautiful/Ferry Corsten - Beautiful (Extended).mp3"}},"id":1}
```

This is working fine. But when there are some none english characters in the string like this:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Playlist.Insert","params":{"playlistid":0,"position":0,"item":{"file":"smb://server/01-Zum Geburtstag viel Glück.mp3"}},"id":1}
```

It is just throwing a "RequestCanceled" Exception.

My c# source is like this:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
                string authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(_username + ":" + _password));
                webRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;

                webRequest.Method = "POST";
                webRequest.UserAgent = "KodiControl";
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

                webRequest.ContentLength = json.Length;
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }
```

The Exception is thrown at `streamWriter.Flush()`. 
So what do I have to do to send this request?``

Comment: just a guess: Maybe you have to encode the request with UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into [Kodi addon unicode paths](http://kodi.wiki/view/Add-on_unicode_paths)
Following that guide will help you prevent common problems with non-latin characters in Kodi.

Python only works with unicode strings internally, converting to a particular encoding on output. (or input)". To make string literals unicode by default, add

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

**Addon path**

```
path = addon.getAddonInfo('path').decode('utf-8')
```

`.decode('utf-8')` tells kodi to decode the given function using `utf-8`. 
Kodi's getAddonInfo returns an UTF-8 encoded string and we decode it an unicode.

**Browse dialog**

```
dialog = xbmcgui.Dialog()
directory = dialog.browse(0, 'Title' , 'pictures').decode('utf-8')
```

dialog.browse() returns an UTF-8 encoded string which perhaps contains some non latin characters. Therefore decode it to unicode!

Comment: Rather than just link to a guide, perhaps you can give some specific info in this post in case that links breaks and future users need help.